# How to overlay Android ViewPagerIndicator on Page viewer?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event, viewpagerindicator

I have implemented the JakeWharton Android-ViewPagerIndicator. I have shared my screens.
This is a two part question: -

1) I want to put the Page Indicator over the Page Viewer. That is the page viewer should be full screen and the Circular Page indicator must fall on this. I making a tutorial for an app and want to use this. It is similar to the Vine app tutorial. I have tried using FrameLayout and RelativeLayout but not able to achieve this.

This is my code and screen shot:

ViewPager_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, rank, country,
            population, flag);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setFades(false);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

2) I want to disable Swipe Left that is I want to move forward only not backward. How do I do this. I tried modifying the circularpageindicator class by checking the previous page number and the current page number. If the previous page number is > that current then i don't do anything. This worked for the Indicator but the page viewer still moves.

Comment: Link for my Screenshot   [link]http://imgur.com/tyg7TlP

Answer (score 0):

Try this to put Indicator overlay on ViewPager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/pager"/>

     <com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to put Indicator on top instead bottom, change

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
```

Hope this help.